# IP address Dynamic or static

Tags: networking, static, wifi, ip-address

I have a laptop and a mobile phone both connected to a common wifi. I need to send data from phone to laptop using MQTT protocol. I would like to know whether  my laptop's IP will change or  will it be the same . If IP will change, then each time I need to change IP address in the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same modem or router to access the internet, it will give you the same IP adres until you are away for an x amount of time (usually weeks or months if not configured). 
Unless you're not using an open wifi network, you're good to go!